# How to add/remove event listener when window's width change

Tags: jquery, html, css

Is there any way to add/remove an event listener which create animation for navbar when window's width change?

when in small screen(e.g. width<768) → if there is an event listener, remove it and fix the navbar on top. No animation display when scroll.

when in large screen  → add an event listener to display animation when scroll

```
<div id="page-header">
<nav class="navbar"> </nav>
</div>

<script>
    var flag = true;
    $(window).on('scroll', function() {
        if ( $(window).scrollTop() > 54 && flag ==true ) {
            console.log('Event Fired');
            $('#page-header nav').css({
                'position': 'fixed',
                'top': '-54px',
                'width': '100%',
                'z-index': '1000'
            })
            .animate({
                top: '+=54px'
            }, 500);
            flag = false;
        } else if ( $(window).scrollTop() === 0 ) {
            $('#page-header nav').css({
                'position': 'relative'
            });
            flag = true;
        }
    });

</script>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the JQuery `off()` method for that.  Rather than placing your handler inline place it in a separate function...

```
function eventHandler(e) {
   /* ... do something ... */
}
```

... and then attach and remove listeners like so ...

```
/* attach */
$('selector').on('event', eventHandler);

/* remove */
$('selector').off('event', eventHandler);
```

As long as the selector, the event, and the handler are an exact match in the 'off' as in the 'on' the behaviour will be removed.

[More info @ JQuery](http://api.jquery.com/off/).

Hope that helps.  :)

Comment: I have no idea why it doesn't work any more when I place the handler in a separate function...And because the selector is window, won't it remove the other scroll event when using .off() method ?

Comment: Oh, now I know that I can add optional namespaces to make events specific.

Comment: found out that my separate function not working because of the parenthesis I added after handler function.  Another problem here is when switch from 'off' to 'on', sometimes it doesn't work. It's unstable.

Comment: @Akito The methods themselves are not unstable, so you must give some attention to the condition which defines when either one of them is implemented. For example, `$(window).on('resize'...` perhaps, and then test window properties to see which one is to be applied.  :)

Comment: Finally it works now. My little stupid mistake again. Thank you for answering  my question   :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Window.matchMedia()`. The API doc is [Window.matchMedia()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/matchMedia)

or for the compatibility, you can listen the `window.onresize` event.

Comment: Yes. I'm trying to use jQuery resize() and need to find a way to detect if there's already a event handler. Because I don't want it add the handler every time window resizing.

Comment: jQuery's external api do not support find a binded event, maybe some internal function can do that,but that's not stable. I suggest via a simple way: ` $(window).unbind('event').on('event',function(){})`

Comment: I use a boolean variable to track the state of event and it works now. Thanks for answering. :)

Answer (score 0):

I do this to detect screen width and set that value in a form hidden field:

```
$(function() {
   var screenwidth = $(window).width();
   $('#screenwidthinput').val(screenwidth);
});
```

You could use that `$(window).width()` call and add or remove the event listener code accordingly.

And JQuery has `resize()` method so you know when the user does it.
https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/event_resize.asp